# How to make a function to check the item related to which feature in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have spend a day on trying out my solution on below problem, but I still cant get the correct way. Here is the problem sample:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Item Id': ['101','102','103', '104'],
        'Feature 1': [1,0,1,0],
        'Feature 2': [0,0,1,0],
        'Feature 3': [1,1,1,0],
        'Feature 4': [0,0,1,1],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Item Id','Feature 1','Feature 2','Feature 3','Feature 4'])

df
```

[image]

I would like to make a function for input **Item Id** then check all the features that related to that **Item Id** and also get the total number of features that item has. The output sample

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sum function to sum all the elements in a row, But then it ll also add your item id, and I don't think you want that. So we make item id as an index and then sum all elements in a row. This way the item id is excluded from the sum.

```
 import pandas as pd

cars = {'Item Id': ['101','102','103', '104'],
        'Feature 1': [1,0,1,0],
        'Feature 2': [0,0,1,0],
        'Feature 3': [1,1,1,0],
        'Feature 4': [0,0,1,1],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Item Id','Feature 1','Feature 2','Feature 3','Feature 4'])
df.set_index('Item Id').sum(axis=1)
```

The index will not be changed permanently,so it doesn't mess us with your table

Comment: Hi @maria_g, thank you for your advice! you have explained in detail and is very clear.

I would like to ask more if any good way to get the list of all features that related to Item ID? For example, **Item Id** has feature 1 and feature 3, when I enter the Item Id into a function, then it will return the list or array of all features that related to the Item Id.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `sum` and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Item Id').sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='No')
print (df)
  Item Id  No
0     101   2
1     102   1
2     103   4
3     104   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `sum` method:

```
import pandas as pd


cars = {'Item Id': ['101','102','103', '104'],
        'Feature 1': [1,0,1,0],
        'Feature 2': [0,0,1,0],
        'Feature 3': [1,1,1,0],
        'Feature 4': [0,0,1,1],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Item Id','Feature 1','Feature 2','Feature 3','Feature 4'])

df['num features'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```